# Calculate end date from month and start date JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a function where I am calculating end date from start date and month (tenure). 
Ex. I have start date `2014-05-05` and adding 1 month into it then it should display `2014-06-05`. Which is showing correct for me.
But If I am adding `2014-02-01` then its showing `2014-03-01` which is wrong. It should display `2014-02-28`.

Following is my function:

```
function getEndDate() {
    var start_date = $("#start_date").val();
    var tenure = $("#tenure").val();

    if (/^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}$/i.test(start_date)) {

        var parts = start_date.split("-");
        var year = parts[0] && parseInt(parts[0], 10);
        var month = parts[1] && parseInt(parts[1], 10);
        var day = parts[2] && parseInt(parts[2], 10);
        var duration = parseInt(tenure, 10);

        if (day <= 31 && day >= 1 && month <= 12 && month >= 1) {
            var expiryDate = new Date(year, month+duration, day);
            expiryDate.setFullYear(expiryDate.getFullYear());

            day = ('0' + expiryDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
            month = ('0' + (expiryDate.getMonth())).slice(-2);
            year = expiryDate.getFullYear();

            $("#end_date").val(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);

        } else {
            // display error message
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Unless you are doing this to learn, you might want to check out the moment library.  http://momentjs.com/   It has all of the date stuff built in plus you can see how they calculate it.

Comment: I don't understand your use case.  If adding one month to 2014-05-05 should correctly yield 2014-06-05, then to me logically adding one month to 2014-02-01 should correctly yield 2014-03-01.  If you're trying to say ' the day before one month' (which would indeed be 2014-02-28 in the latter case) then the former case should have yielded 2014-06-04, not 2014-06-05.

Comment: @Paul: It should know the days of the particular month. eg. Feb has only 28 or 29 days.

Comment: I ran your simulation in .NET just to see what it would return and it shows 3/1/2014 in your second use case.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/gdvROt  Then I ran it using the momentjs library which also calculates 3/1/2014.  http://plnkr.co/edit/c0Gfqi6c7pSMkXTaSUZS?p=preview

Comment: I have updated my post. please check

Comment: Why is `2014-03-01` wrong if you are adding one month?

Comment: @Ultimate but you said you wanted to add one month, not add 30 days.  There's a difference both logically and in the language.

Answer (score 0):

When you add dates the easiest way it to sum milliseconds, like in the previous example i made, or manipulating the date object like this:

```
date = new Date(); //current date
future_date = new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDay(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds());


//date -> Wed May 28 2014 21:43:52 GMT+0200 (CEST)    
//future_date -> Sun Jun 03 114 21:43:52 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Comment: How is 1 month equal to 31 days? If we are talking in terms of month, using months is always a better way as it considers the number of days in a given month.

Comment: @Ankit Jaiswal - Good point, in my example i've just assumed that the end user would trim the day value in relation to the days in that particular month. Anyway i've modified the script as you suggested.

Comment: you updated the code but the description is still the same. :)

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal yep sorry! i'm a little bit distracted.. :)